# Error showing up while printing GCD

Tags: java, loops

> I came across a question which says to input two numbers and print
>   their GCD(Greatest common Divisor).

Here is the code which i wrote:

```
import java.io.*;
class gcd {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{ 

       static int m=0;
       static int gcd=0;

       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       System.out.println("Enter two integers");
       String s1=br.readLine();
       int g1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
       String s2=br.readLine();
       int g2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
       int maxim=Math.max(g1,g2);
       int minim=Math.min(g1,g2);

       while(m!=0){
           m = maxim % minim;
           if(m == 0){
               gcd=minim;
           }
           maxim=minim;
           minim=m;
        }
        System.out.println("GCD="+minim);

        }
    }
```

If i enter two numbers, say `25` and `45`, the GCD result should be `5`. However, the output is coming as `25`.

Please find out the error in my code.

Comment: Using the debugger of whichever IDE you use should do the trick

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile, let alone run. How did you even get `20` out of it?

Comment: Sorry, i just corrected that by editing, please refresh.

Comment: I am using BlueJ IDE

Comment: _”Please find the error in my code”_ — Sorry StackOverflow does not work this way.  Read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still be getting compilation errors with declaration of 'm' and 'gcd' as static. You do not need to declare them static.

The other bug you have is, you are initializing m to 0, and the while loop statement is

```
   while(m!=0){
```

so the while loop will not get executed even once since the condition 'm != 0' is false. This explains why the output is 25 when your input is 45 and 25. Consider using a do-while loop so that the loop gets executed at least once. Another bug is that your final print statement is printing the value of 'minim', is that what you want? Shouldn't you be printing the variable that stores the final gcd value. I have given you all the hints so that you have the satisfaction of fixing the bugs by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I will recommend to create a function and then do the calculation.

Your code is incorrect

```
maxim = 45
minim = 25
m = maxim %minim // m=45%25 = 20
m !=0
maxim = minim // maxim=minim=25
m=minim // m=25

//In your next iteration
maxim=25
minim=25
m = maxim %minim // m=25%25 = 0
m==0 
gcd= minim // i.e 25
```

So, your code is incorrect

Try this -

```
public static void gcd(int a, int b)
{
   if(a==b)
      return a;
   else if(a>b)
      return gcd(a-b,b);
   else
      return gcd(a,b-a);
}
```